# ImportError: No module named etree in Jython

Tags: python, python-2.7, ibm-midrange, jython-2.5

I am trying to parse a text file and convert it to xml file. 
For that i got one code(**python3**) which got executed successfully on my windows machine.
 
But, the same code when i wanted to execute on my AS400 machine with jython its throwing error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):        
  File "<string>", line 2, in ?    
ImportError: No module named etree
```

Here is the python script that worked for me on windows .

Please help me how can i resolve this issue.

**Python code:**

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys
rex = re.compile(r'''(?P<title>Web\s+Name
                       |Context\s+Root
                       |Status

                       )
                     \s*:?\s*
                     (?P<value>.*)
                     ''', re.VERBOSE)

root = ET.Element('root')
root.text = '\n'    # newline before the celldata element

with open('WasContent.txt') as f:

    celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'celldata')
    celldata.text = '\n'    # newline before the collected element
    celldata.tail = '\n\n'  # empty line after the celldata element
    for line in f:
        # Empty line starts new celldata element (hack style, uggly)
        if line.isspace():
            celldata = ET.SubElement(root, 'celldata')
            celldata.text = '\n'
            celldata.tail = '\n\n'

        # If the line contains the wanted data, process it.
        m = rex.search(line)
        if m:
            # Fix some problems with the title as it will be used
            # as the tag name.
            title = m.group('title')
            title = title.replace('&', '')
            title = title.replace(' ', '')

            e = ET.SubElement(celldata, title.lower())
            e.text = m.group('value')
            e.tail = '\n'

# Display for debugging
#ET.dump(root)

# Include the root element to the tree and write the tree
# to the file.
#tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
            tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
#tree.write('cell.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
            tree.write('cell.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=Tru
```

**Text File i am reading as input:**

> ------------------------------------- Checking websphere application status
>   -------------------------------------- WASX7209I: Connected to process "SERVER1" on node SRVR_SRVR using SOAP connector;  The type of process
>   is: UnManagedProcess
>   +----------------------------+
>  
>  Status: Stopped
>   +----------------------------+
>   +----------------------------+
>  CtxRootForWebMod: Specify the Context root of web module
>
> Configure values for context roots in web modules. 
>  Web module: 
>   SessionTest.war
>  URI:  SessionTest.war,WEB-INF/web.xml
>  Context
>   Root:  /aaa
>  Status: Running
>   +----------------------------+
>   +----------------------------+
>  CtxRootForWebMod: Specify the Context root of web module
>
> Configure values for context roots in web modules.
>  
>  Web
>   module:  WebApp
>  URI: 
>   MainApp_934v123_20150605.war,WEB-INF/web.xml
>  Context Root: 
>   /mainapp_icilif
>  Status: Stopped
>   +----------------------------+
>   +----------------------------+

**output:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <root>

<celldata> <webmodule>SessionTest.war</webmodule> <contextroot>/aaa</contextroot> <status>Running</status> </celldata>

<celldata> <webmodule>MainApp_934v123_20150605.war</webmodule> <contextroot>/mainapp_icilif</contextroot> <status>Stopped</status> </celldata>


</root>
```

Comment: What is your jython version? If it's lower than 2.7, I'm not sure it'll work.

Comment: ElementTree was added in Jython 2.5.0 (http://www.jython.org/latest.html).